# How to recover the spatial probability distribution of a GPS location from its accuracy?

Tags: gps, android-gps, data-processing, probability-density, probability-distribution

A location coordinate determined by GPS  is not perfectly accurate. It follows a probability distribution. An Android location comes with an accuracy property. [The Android Developer docs for `Location.getAccuracy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) says:

> We define horizontal accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence.

Theoretically, what kind of probability distribution does this GPS location follow? I have read some non-authoritative articles that say it follows a normal distribution. And why is the number 68% chosen?

Suppose we know this distribution. With this given location's coordinate and accuracy, how do we recover its probability distribution (probability density function)? Namely how do we determine the unknown parameters of this probability density function?

Moreover, satellite data can also be obtained. Can it help refine the distribution even more?